# Cap duration of UIDatePickerView in mode UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I need users to be able to select a duration, which it looks like `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` is made for, but I want to cap it at, say, three hours, which it looks like it isn't.

Can I do this with `UIDatePicker`, or would I be better off creating a custom two-column `UIPickerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
[pkrTime setMinuteInterval:3];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *defaultDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01-01-2000 00:03:00"];
[dateFormatter release];

[pkrTime setMinimumDate:defaultDate];
```

Comment: I wanted maximum rather than minimum, but `setMaximumDate` ought to do the trick. :) Thanks!